# How can I generate a Django model class from an abstract class using a decorator or factory?

Tags: python, django, entity-attribute-value

For a few projects, we are using a very simple variation of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). We don't need filtering and querying over datasets. We have looked at [django-eav](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav) and [eav-django](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/eav-django), they are not suitable for our projects, mainly because we do not want to use GenericForeignKey.

The basic setup we are looking at now is this (fields not needed for this question are left out to focus on the question at hand):

```
# In the EAV app

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max-Length=100, unique=True)


class BaseValue(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

In an app that uses attributes, we can do this:

```
# Locations with attributes

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class LocationValue(BaseValue):
    object = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

This serves out purposes well, but it would be nice if we could just generate the LocationValue class. So what we would like to do, but cannot get to work is this:

Option 1, decorator

```
# Locations with attributes

@has_attrs
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max-Length=100, unique=True)

# The `has_attrs` decorator should generate the LocationValue class
```

Option 2, generator / factory

```
# Locations with attributes

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max-Length=100, unique=True)


LocationValue = value_class_for(Location)
# The function `value_class_for` should generate the LocationValue class
```

It is important that the LocationValue class is part of the same app as Location. The reason for this is that we want the database model to be understandable even for those who look at it directly (not through the Django abstraction layer).

Also, there will be more than one app that uses this, so in the end we would have maybe a locations app (Location, LocationValue), a Monument app (Monument, MonumentValue), et cetera.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to delegate the generation of the LocationValue class to a models.Model decorator or factory function?
2. What are advantages / disadvantages of available solutions, if any?

Thanks if you share your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic way of achieving this would be using a [metaclass](http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/metaclass/), which is invoked when the classes are *created* the first time. So you can take control over class creation and also create additional classes (consider it as some sort of "factory" for classes). Django also takes big advantage of this "magic" when setting up the model classes. You may want to have a look at [Django's `ModelBase` metaclass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L65) which creates the `Model` classes (furthermore you would probably need to subclass this to integrate the functionality you want).